# Select a particular node to run a test in a Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have set up a Selenium Grid having one normal Chrome node and one debug node. There are some cases where I would like to run a case on the debug node.

I am using docker-compose to manage the Grid and the only way I can do this via docker-compose so far is to have different image for debug node.

I have read few answers where they have referred specifying an application name or a different version to the nodes that I can then use in the desired capability of my code.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use applicationName.  There's a bug to document it:

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3660

The bug details how to start a node with a given `applicationName` via the `-brower` parameter, e.g.:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node -hub http://HUB_IP:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=11,maxInstances=1,platform=WINDOWS,applicationName=windows7_32bits_firefox_11
```

And then in your tests, you add the capability, e.g.:

> In your tests you have to add 
>   "applicationName=windows7_32bits_firefox_11" to your desired 
>   capabilities array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ernie. However I was looking for a way to specify the applicationName or the version via docker-compose file.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that your question was purely around the docker configuration.  Probably a better question for SO or some other StackExchange, as that's not really SQA specific

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem. You can use param `NODE_APPLICATION_NAME=your-app-name` in docker-compose file. It's an old question, but maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28144)

Comment: @NitinRastogi I'm not sure this "doesn't answer the question". It may indeed be an incorrect answer (I don't know) but it does certainly appear to be an answer.

Comment: @NitinRastogi author clarified that he was using docker-compose, so I gave him proper parameter. Your link contains "Answers don't have to be exhaustive or infallible, they just need to try to answer the question".